# Boolean Expressions Evaluator Error

Tags: c, boolean, logic, expression, lex

I am working on making a boolean expression evaluator in lex and c, however I am having problem finding the error in my code.

When I run the code the parser.c file throws the `error("expected end-of-file")`. This means that the program is not reading the end of file character, and I cannot find where this is going wrong.

I have attached the problematic code below. If, to solve this issue you need to see some more of the code please let me know, and I will be happy to post them also. I have been stuck on this problem for several weeks not, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Lexer.h

```
#ifndef ____lexer__
#define ____lexer__

#include <stdio.h>

#define AND 258
#define OR 259
#define NOT 260
#define TRUE 261
#define FALSE 262

#define DONE 300
#define NONE (-1)

int lexan();

extern int value;
extern int lineNo;
extern char lexbuf[];
extern FILE *fileSource;
#endif /* defined(____lexer__) */
```

lexer.lex

```
%{
    #include <ctype.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include "lexer.h"
    #include "error.h"

    int value;
    int lineNo;
%}

%option noyywrap

%%
['''\t']* {}
['\n']* { lineNo++; }

<<EOF>> {
    return DONE;
}

"True"  {return (TRUE);}
"False" {return (FALSE);}
"or"    {return (OR);}
"and"   {return (AND);}
"not"   {return (NOT);}
.|\n {
    value = NONE;
    int temp = (int)(yytext[0]);
    return (temp);
}
%%

int lexan()
{
    yyin = fileSource;
    int result = yylex();
    return result;
}
```

parser.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "parser.h"
#include "lexer.h"
#include "error.h"
#include "interpreter.h"

static int lookahead;

static void stmts();
static void stmt();
static void assign();
static void expr();
static void match();

void parse()
{
    lookahead = lexan();
    stmts();
    lookahead = lexan();
    if(lookahead != DONE)
        error("expected end-of-file");
}

static void stmts()
{
    while (lookahead != DONE)
    {
        if(lookahead == AND || lookahead == OR || lookahead == NOT || lookahead == TRUE || lookahead == FALSE)
        {
            stmt();
        }
        else
            break;
    }
}

static void stmt()
{
    switch (lookahead)
    {
        case AND:
            emit(AND);
            match(AND);
            break;
        case OR:
            emit(OR);
            match(OR);
            break;
        case NOT:
            emit(NOT);
            match(NOT);
            break;
        default:
            assign();
    }
}

static void assign()
{
    switch (lookahead)
    {
        case TRUE:
            emit(TRUE);
            match(TRUE);
            break;
        case FALSE:
            emit(FALSE);
            match(FALSE);
        default:
            error("syntax error");
    }
}

void match(int t)
{
    if (lookahead == t)
    {
        lookahead = lexan();
    }
    else
        error("syntax error");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate problem is that `lookahead` is already `DONE` if `stmts()` returns successfully. Calling `yylex` again after it hits EOF is undefined behaviour, but you really don't want to do the call because the logic is incorrect; `lookahead` hasn't yet been matched when `stmts()` returns so the caller should attempt to match it, not overwrite it with a new token.

Fixing that is the least of your problems, though. The logic of `stmts` and `stmt` are also wrong; you need to reread whatever guide/text you are using to write a recursive descent parser.

By the way, if you don't have an `<<EOF>>` rule, `yylex` will return 0 when it hits the end of input. You should consider making use of this behaviour rather than producing a custom return code.